# Configuration Error while running the site from visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to run my website using The Visual Studio 2012 built in Server. I receive this error. I get this error (Note I am not using a virtual directory or an IIS Server just the Visual Studio 2012):

```
Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error: 


Line 30:       </buildProviders>
Line 31:     </compilation>
Line 32:        <authentication mode="None">
Line 33:            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
Line 34:       

Source File: D:\work\latest\NewPortal16-11\NewPortal8\newportal8\web.config    Line: 32 


Show Additional Configuration Errors:
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34249
```

Comment: You tagged your question with visual-studio-2010. Is it 2010 or 2012?

Comment: And what is the root of your application? Is it D:\work\latest\NewPortal16-11\NewPortal8? Because in that case, you have a web.config file under a standard folder newportal8 (...\newportal8\newportal8) which is allowed but not considered as an web application configuration file thus causing the error